# PostgreSQL Update From Values Treats Nulls As Text

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, executemany

Need help in solving an issue when one of the values' columns contains only `Null` values. Example:

```sql
create table foo (
    id serial constraint foo_pk primary key,
    a int,
    b int
);

insert into foo (a,b) values (1, 1), (2, 2);

update foo t
set a = v.a, b = v.b
from (values (1, NULL, 1),(2, NULL, 2)) as v(id, a, b)
where v.id = t.id;
```

This gives me:

```
[42804] ERROR: column "a" is of type integer but expression is of type text 
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 22
```

I'm using `psycopg2.extras.execute_values` in order to update multiple Django ORM objects. Looking for a solution that doesn't need to cast nulls to field types explicitly.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Used the solution #5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As all the values you've passed for column `a` are `NULL`s , Postgres will implicitly consider them to be `TEXT`s

You have 2 options,

cast the value of `a` to int in the `SET` expression.

```
set a = v.a::int
```

OR

cast one of the values of `a` to `INT`, from which the other values will default to.

```
values (1, NULL::int, 1),(2, NULL, 2)) as v(id, a, b)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3e187aa9ad17263463c9747901bffec4)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kaushik. Sorry, I didn't mention earlier that I need a solution that works without explicit cast. Like this:

`sql update foo set a = null, b = null where id = 1;`

As update statements are being constructed automatically based on ORM objects passed into a function.